# Unable to display rich media ads in ios 9

Tags: ios, google-dfp, rich-media

I am using `DFP banner` to show ads,I am able to show rich media ad creative in iOS 8 but the same ad is unable to load in iOS 9.

Let me clear you the image ads are loading properly in iOS 9, the problem is only with `rich media creative`. I have also set Enable bit code to No and configured the `NSAppTransportSecurity` which are considerations to be done in iOS 9.

So kindly let me know if someone has a solution.I am stucked badly because of this issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Just to follow up; For us this ended up being a matter of mixed content rather than a problem with rich media.